# rsync subfolder to different folder name

Tags: rsync

When I do this:

```
rsync folder/a /mnt/some/destination
```

I end up with `/mnt/some/destination/folder/a`, but what I want is for the contents of `folder/a` to be *directly* inside `/mnt/some/destination`.

I know this is possible if I do this:

```
rsync folder/a/* /mnt/some/destination
```

However, and this is the key to the issue, is that this doesn't work with the `--delete` option.  That option requires the source to be a directory, so the wildcard doesn't work.

A workaround would be to

```
cd folder/a && rsync --delete . /mnt/some/destination
```

Is there a way to do this without changing the working directory?  My scenario is CD/CI build environment.

Are there any options like the `tar -C`, or `wget --cut-dirs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
rsync folder/a  /mnt/some/destination
```

use:

```
rsync folder/a/ /mnt/some/destination
```

That will allow `--delete` to delete files in the destination that don't exist in the source and also puts the contents of `folder/a` directly into `/mnt/some/destination/`.